# flask getting celery AsyncResult task via id returns incorrect task

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to get celery running with flask and then show the result, according to this tutorial: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask. But after the task successfully finished, the flask app still sees a "pending" task. The way of grabbing the task via id apparently does not return the same task object.

When I hook into the `longtask()` function, `task.state` is first "PENDING" and then after 15 seconds it's "SUCCESS" like it should be. Then the celery worker also returns the result, so that part works. But in the `taskstatus()` function where I get the task via `task = long_task.AsyncResult(task_id)`, `task.state` always stays "PENDING" and other attributes like `task.info` stay `None`. Why does that happen and how can I access my task object properly?

```
Python 3.8.16 
Flask 2.2.2 
celery 5.2.7
RabbitMQ 3.11.9
```

My system is Windows unfortunately but in general it should work according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255548/how-to-run-celery-on-windows) post. So I start my celery worker like this:

```
celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info --pool=eventlet
```

code:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, url_for, jsonify
from celery import Celery

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'amqp://celery:celery@localhost:5672/' 
app.config['result_backend'] = 'rpc://celery:celery@localhost:5672/' 

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
celery.set_default()

@celery.task(bind=True)
def long_task(self):
    for i in range(15):
        message = '{0} {1} {2}...'
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
                          meta={'current': i, 'total': 15,
                                'status': message})
        time.sleep(1)
    return {'status': 'Done'}

@app.route('/longtask', methods=['POST'])
def longtask():
    task = long_task.apply_async()  # after 15 seconds: task.state == "SUCCESS"
    return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('taskstatus', task_id=task.id)}

@app.route('/status/<task_id>')
def taskstatus(task_id):
    task = long_task.AsyncResult(task_id)  # task.state always "PENDING" 
    return jsonify({'result': task.state})
```

the celery worker returns a success after 15 seconds:

```
[2023-02-22 16:06:57,697: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.long_task[37a4e58c-857b-470c-823e-d6b9759458e3] received
[2023-02-22 16:07:11,847: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.long_task[37a4e58c-857b-470c-823e-d6b9759458e3] succeeded in 14.140999999945052s: {'status': 'Done'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 1,5 days of research and despair, I found the answer myself. The reason is the rpc backend which does not store the tasks (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484905/getting-celery-task-results-using-rpc-backend) post), as described in the [celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#task-result-backends).

I'm still wondering, since ampq seems deprecated as backend, is there another way to use rabbitmq as backend in which task values are stored? Or do I have to setup redis or mysql now?

Edit:
I did setup redis and it works. Had to install Ubuntu and redis and then simply change the backend path:

```
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'amqp://celery:celery@localhost:5672/'
app.config['result_backend'] = 'redis://localhost/'
```

Comment: Being deprecated does not mean you can't use it. I know many people who still use RabbitMQ as broker. Keep in mind RabbitMQ Celery broker is (together with Redis one) the most complete broker implementation for Redis (remote control API, etc).

Comment: I am not going to drop rabbitmq as a broker but I´m not sure how to use RPC as backend? I now chose to use redis as backend and it works without problems. But If anyone has advice for retrieving results with flask via RPC, I´d be happy happy to learn about that